# Script time leakage

Tags: python, file, file-upload

I created script to upload data in every 10 minutes. it works but after uploading several times, there is 1 minute gap.
 It starts like that
2019/10/01 10:00 2019/10/01 10:10
After running script several times it show below result
2019/10/01 19:01 2019/10/01 19:11

How to modify it always record and upload exactly in 10:00 minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post here your actual code (just the part which triggers the 10 to 10 min thing), you may be missing something

Comment: This is not an answer, please remove it and put is as a comment.

Comment: sheet=wb.active
            d2=sheet['D62']
            d1=sheet['D1']
            b2=sheet['B62']
            c1=sheet['D63']
            #print(d2.value, d1)
            list0.append(d2.value)
            d[d1]= list0
            #print (sum(list),list)
            #print ("lengh",len(list))
            time.sleep(2)
            #print(c1.value, d1)
            list1.append(c1.value)
            d[c1]= list0
            #print (sum(list1),list1)
            #print ("lengh",len(list1))
            time.sleep(60)